# Android application 'on hold'; 'duplicate';'closed' etc

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

I use android application to view question and answer them. Sometime i confuse with title of question which has been already marked on hold duplicate or closed. In web interface they get updated and shown in list (added to title in bracket)but in android app its missing. Am i missing something here?

Comment: You're right it isn't there. It is shown when opening the question. I agree with you that it should be shown in the title, the same as it is on the site.

Comment: I can't help myself, but this is funny. So there's a well stated feature request/bug report. Then one person comments that they agree, this comment gets upvoted twice, and yet the question has +1-0 score (moreover, I upvoted both the comment and the Q).